# Translating っつーか

Tags: grammar, translation, particles

I really really need help with this sentence I have tried everything but I don't get its structure and how to translate it so I'd appreciate if someone could help please?

> オレ一人 ore hitori
>   チャラチャラしても charachara shitemo
>   浮くっつーか uku ttsuuka
>   恥ずかしい hazukashii

Someone told me that 浮くっつーか--> つーか is very colloquial, the original is "というか" = "と言えるかもしれない" means "perhaps I should say".
but it still doesn't make sense to me.

My rough translation is:

"Even if I am the only one who is talkative that would be inappropriate and embarrassing"

Total fail and bad English translation I know. Also it really doesn't fit with the context.

Please can someone help?

Comment: Is this from song lyrics or manga?

Comment: 「つーか」>> http://zokugo-dict.com/18tu/tu-ka.htm　...or...  http://www.websaru.org/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%86%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B;%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B;%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A4%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8B;%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A4%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B;%E3%81%A4%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8B;%E3%81%A6%E3%82%86%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8B;%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8B.html

Comment: 「チャラチャラする/した」には「軽薄な」「浮ついた」「(服装が)派手な」「気取った」などの意味もありますが・・・

Answer (score 3):

Glad that you gave the translation a try!  *(I think that in itself should keep this question open for answers... at the very least.)*

Anyway, from looking at your original text, I would possibly translate this as:

> Even if it's just me going on and on [in talking], I feel out of place (and it feels awkward.)

Would this make any sense given the context?  If not, would you be able to provide any more source context for the given sentence?

Comment: Thank you summea, your reply was helpful c: ofc I have tried to translate this sentence XD
Anyway thanks to you I got the meaning of it. The context is:"Two friends are going out, one guy always wears normal clothes while the other one wears "flashy" clothes" given the situation the guy that usually wears "flashy clothes" decides to wear normal clothes just as his friend not to feel out of place."
So my translation now is:
"Or rather I should say that if I am the only one showing off it would be embarrassing and it would grab unwanted attention"
It makes much more sense xD

Comment: @Dai Nice work :)

Comment: Where do you get "going on and on [in talking]" from?

Comment: @TokyoNagoya When this question came up, I didn't quite know what the context was for the original phrase in the question... looking back at this question now, it makes sense about this being related to "clothing" instead of "chattering" (especially after Dai's comment to this answer.) "on and on" comes from the interpretation that チャラチャラ can also mean "chatty".