# Meaning of っつーかなんつーか

Tags: meaning, nuances, use-and-frequency, repetition-structure

I have difficulty to understand っつーか in the following context

> 身体に良くないと思うけど」
>   「好き**っつーかなんつーか**」 　
>    オレはカップ形状のものを手に取って、それから値札を見る。
>
> I don’t think it’s really good for the body though.”
>   “Eh, I was just
>   considering if I should buy it.”
>   I picked up a cup noodles bowl and
>   looked at the price.

I know the term has been treated in

[Translating っつーか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11862/translating-%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a4%e3%83%bc%e3%81%8b)

and is a colloquial form of と言うか (or perhaps I should say; or, how should I put it,...; I mean)

but I cannot figure how it works in the context (specially the duplication)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you already figured out つーか = というか, you can see by analogy that this expression is というかなんというか in its full form.

This is an idiom, close to filler. If broken down literally, Xというかなんというか means "not sure if it is X or something other". It embraces more "hesitation" than mere というか, and is used chiefly in two kinds of situations:

1. when X is close but there might be better words which one cannot recall at once

   > 好きというかなんというか
   >   Perhaps I kind of like it or something...
2. when X is a less than perfect way to say it but one cannot find a correct word at once

   > 好きというかなんというか
   >   I don't exactly like it, it's rather...